# Does Firebase know when data is no longer a part of query?

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

In my Firebase database, I have children containing Unix times, and I'm querying by times that occur after the current time. I'm putting the data of each child which matches that criteria into a `UICollectionView`. When the current time surpasses the time of one of the children, I want for the child to expire, and to get removed from the `UICollectionView`. Currently, it isn't getting removed until I restart the app. Here is some of the code:

```
// in viewDidLoad
self.events_query = Database.database().reference().child("events").queryOrdered(byChild: "end-time").queryStarting(atValue: Date().timeIntervalSince1970)

// in viewWillAppear
func observeAllEvents() {
    self.events_query.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        guard let eids_dict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] else { return }
        let eids = Array(eids_dict.keys)

        for eid in eids {
            print(eid)
        }

        Event.getAllEvents(with: eids, ref: self.events_query.ref, completion: { (events) in

            if let feed_datasource = self.datasource as? EventFeedDatasource {
                feed_datasource.events = events
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            }
        })

    })
}

// in viewDidDisappear
self.events_query.removeAllObservers()
```

Here's the function `getAllEvents`:

```
static func getAllEvents(with eids: [String], ref: DatabaseReference, completion: @escaping (_ events: [Event]) -> Void) {
    var events = [Event]()
    let dispatch_groups = [DispatchGroup(), DispatchGroup()]

    for eid in eids {
        dispatch_groups[0].enter()
        ref.child(eid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] else { return }
            dispatch_groups[1].enter()

            // I'm not including `load` because all it does is parse the snapshot
            Event.load(with: dictionary, completion: { (event) in
                events.append(event)
                dispatch_groups[1].leave()
            })
            dispatch_groups[0].leave()
        })
    }

    dispatch_groups[0].notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
        dispatch_groups[1].notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
            completion(events)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, Firebase knows precisely when a child node is no longer part of a query. In your code, when that happens it fires a `value` event where that child node is no longer present in the `snapshot. But it's a bit hard to parse the code with the nested listeners and methods. Can you reproduce the problem in a [single, minimal snippet of code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you can, and also share your JSON, I can give it a quick spin. You can get this JSON by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: I'm now listening for `.childAdded`, `.childChanged`, and `.childRemoved` events. Do I have to listen for `.value` in order to detect a child which is no longer part of a query? I notice that `.childMoved` also exists; is it of use in this case?